# how to save the array data into mysql database

Tags: php, arrays

stated array getting set of combinations....please help me and let me know how to save list of record into mysql database.....database contains three fields (set1 set2 set3)...

regards,

```
$array1 = array('rough', 'smooth', 'coarse'); 
$array2 = array('shiny', 'matte', 'rough'); 
$array3 = array('very large', 'large', 'medium', 'small'); 

$array=array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3); 

$combinations=array(); 
for($x=0;$x<(count($array)-2);$x++) { 
$a=$array[$x]; 
for ($y=$x+1;$y<count($array);$y++) { 
    $b=$array[$y]; 
    for ($z=$y+1;$z<count($array);$z++) { 
        $c=$array[$z]; 
        $combinations[]="$a, $b, $c"; 
    } 
} 
}
```

Comment: Consider *more normalization*. If the data is *ever* queried or is part of business rules it is usually the appropriate route. Otherwise, the keyword is "serialize".

Comment: if you guys help me with the code i will appreciate...xx

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just use `json_encode()` to turn the array into JSON before storing. This way the data can be available to other processes and languages with minimal hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function to turn the array into a string.

Once retrieved, you can then use the [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to turn it back into an array.